# An action of an automorphism of a field $C$ on a variety $X$ over $C$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

My question comes from the reading of the first two pages of the article "Bernhard Köck - Belyi's Theorem Revisited".

Consider a field $C$ and a variety $X$ over $C$. In particular $X$ is a separated, integral scheme with a structure morphism $f:X\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}C=\{(0)\}$ of finite type (in this case the morphism $f$ is the constant morphism that sends $X$ to $(0)$). If $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}C$, the author defines the variety $X^\sigma$ over $C$ in the following way:

> As scheme, the variety $X^\sigma$ is $X$, but the structure morphism is $\operatorname{Spec} (\sigma)\circ f: X\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec} C$

Now since $\operatorname{Spec} C$ is a point, it is evident that $\operatorname{Spec}(\sigma):C\longrightarrow C$ is the identity wich sends $(0)$ to $(0)$ and it follows that $\operatorname{Spec} (\sigma)\circ f=f$. For this reason for me $X$ and $X^\sigma$ are **the same object**!  I'dont understand the difference between the varieties $X$ and $X^\sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A morphism of schemes is not determined by the underlying map on topological spaces!  There is also a map of sheaves to consider.

For example, take $C = X=\mathbb{C}$, and let $\sigma: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be complex conjugation.  Then $\sigma$ gives rise to a morphism of schemes $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}\to\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ which is different from the identity map—even though they both are the same map of one-point topological spaces.

Comment: Ok, this is clear, many thanks! But it is strange that $X$ and $X^\sigma$ could be also non isomorphic varieties. Intuitively I image that they are isomorphic.

Comment: @Galoisfan: it is indeed a bit subtle: $X$ and $X^{\sigma}$ are isomorphic as schemes, but not as schemes over $\mathbb{C}$.  If you know about elliptic curves, I recommend you think about what happens when you take an elliptic curve with $j$-invariant $i$ and hit it with complex conjugation.  The $j$-invariant changes to $-i$, so we get a nonisomorphic Riemann surface.

Comment: Here is what this looks like on the algebraic side: if $S$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, it may also be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra in two different ways, each compatible with the real structure.  The simplest example is $\mathbb{C}$ itself, which can be equipped with the $\mathbb{C}$-action $i\cdot z := -iz$!